# Is there a class diagram for JavaPlatform SE 8 all classes?

Tags: java, java-8, class-diagram

I was wondering. Is there a Classe diagram for every class in Java Platform Standard Edition 8 ?

Something that will simplify , that can be incorporeted to API Specification.

Any idea about this ? generated by someone ?

Comment: A diagram containing all classes in Java 8 would be quite unreadable.

Comment: not necessary in one file .... but multiple per package for example ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer this [Hierarchy For All Packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/overview-tree.html) which contains the Class Hierarchy. You can also refer the [list of all classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/allclasses-noframe.html) in Java8

Comment: well, thank you, I know this , I am talking about a real diagram ?

Comment: @OSryx:- You can use [Class Visualizer](http://www.class-visualizer.net/) which will generate UML Class Diagram but I dont think that there is any such documented UML diagram for all the classes.

Answer (score 2):

There are close to 4000 classes in Java 8. Getting them all together on 1 paper will make it all mess.

I have recently started posting such class diagrams on my site. Here are few sample , if they are of help to you -

http://www.buggybread.com/2015/09/java-class-diagram-collections-classes.html

http://www.buggybread.com/2015/10/java-javaio-stream-classes.html

http://www.buggybread.com/2015/10/java-se-list-of-formatexception.html

http://www.buggybread.com/2015/10/java-se-javalang-string-classes.html

http://www.buggybread.com/2015/10/java-se-date-classes.html

http://www.buggybread.com/2015/10/java-se-time-classes.html

http://www.buggybread.com/2015/10/class-diagram-java-se-javautil-map_2.html

Let me know if you have any other specific need ( like all classes in a package , classes that implement an interface , classes having a keyword etc ), let me know and I will post them too.